# how to add model to razor page with jquery ajax in asp.net mvc 5?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

i want add model value to razor page with jquery ajax
with this code i can get value list:

```
<script>
        $.ajax({
            url: "/TechnicalInfoGroups",
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {

                console.log(data);


            }
        });
    </script>
```

[image]
but i want add this data to my razor page model But I do not know how to do it

my controller code:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var appDbContext = _context.TechnicalInfoGroups.Include(t => t.Products);
            var model = await appDbContext.ToListAsync();
           
            return Json(model);
        }
```

Comment: Do you want to add the data to razor page?Such as show it in a table.Or you just need to add it to page model?

Comment: @YiyiYou I want to display the data in a table but I need to be able to use it in the next step and send an element of this list as a post to the controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demo to get list from controller and put it into table,and after button click pass the list to controller(If you want,you can also choose an element of the list to pass):

ModelA:

```
public class ModelA
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
        public string Products { get; set; }

        public string ProductId { get; set; }

        public string TechnicalInfos { get; set; }

    }
```

View:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div id="tableArea">
    <table id="table1">
        <thead>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<button onclick="getTable()">getTable</button>
<button onclick="submit()">submit</button>
```

js:

```
<script>
        function getTable() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Test/Index",
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#table1 thead").append('<tr><td>Id</td><td>GroupName</td><td>Products</td><td>ProductId</td><td>TechnicalInfos</td></tr>');
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        $("#table1 tbody").append('<tr><td> ' + item["id"] + '</td><td>' + item["groupName"] + '</td><td>' + item["products"] + '</td><td>' + item["productId"] + '</td><td>' + item["technicalInfos"] + '</td></tr>');
                    });


                }
            });
        }
        function submit() {

        $this=$('#table1 tbody').children("tr:first");
        var obj = {};
        obj.Id = parseInt($this.find("td").eq(0).text());
        obj.GroupName = $this.find("td").eq(1).text();
        obj.Products = $this.find("td").eq(2).text();
        obj.ProductId = $this.find("td").eq(3).text();
        obj.TechnicalInfos = $this.find("td").eq(4).text();
       
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("GetList", "Test")",
            data: obj,
            headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
            success: function (data) {
              
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
```

TestController(Use fake data to test):

```
public class TestController : Controller
    {
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {

            List<ModelA> l = new List<ModelA> {
                new ModelA{  Id=1, GroupName="ssdd"},
                new ModelA{  Id=2, GroupName="ssdd2"},
                new ModelA{  Id=3, GroupName="ssdd3"},
                new ModelA{  Id=4, GroupName="ssdd4"},
                new ModelA{  Id=5, GroupName="ssdd5"}

            };
            return Json(l);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult GetList(ModelA modelA)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer get list Works well  Now I want to be able to send one of the list elements in your function sent all elements

Comment: I have changed my answer,and it can only send one element to controller action.You can have a look.